# How to add Files on my computer into local mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a folder in my computer containing a list of files in json and bson format to be added into my local mongodb. The name of the db is sahaj_dev. [This is the image of the list of files on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jXwh.png)

I have to add all these files to my sahaj_dev database as  collections of that database.

How can I do it. I am not sure whether to use mongoimport or mongostore. I am new to mongodb. Kindly help me out with the command to be used. Thanks. [This is the image of database to which I have to add all the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3OQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for it. I have to use the mongorestore command. The syntax of it is

```
mongorestore -d <db_name> <location of the folder>
```

This would restore all the files in the folder and create respective collections for it in the local mongoDB